# iPad Ok but on iPhone (Cocos2D 1.0.1) Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

When I run my app as iPad on device/simulator everything is ok
but when I run it as iPhone I get the Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch problem.

I am on XCode 5.
I do not have a RootViewController/viewcontrollers in my application delegate because I am using Cocos2D.

In my application Delegate I do stuff like

CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();

```
// Obtain the shared director in order to...
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

// Turn on display FPS
[director setDisplayFPS:YES];

// Set multiple touches on
EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];   
[glView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
// Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    NSLog(@"Retina Display Not supported");
[director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
```

Will this be fixed If I just create some kind of nib file for my main window? as I lack a Mainwindow Nib

Comment: google it, it's a common problem

Comment: @LearnCocos2D i did google it but none of it helps. I've looked 10 threads. They all say to set rootviewcontroller but my Cocos2D code doesnt seem to have any viewcontroller/doesnt have main nib

Comment: it used to work fine I don't know what I broke to make it stop working Help me out @LearnCocos2D i swear i exhausted all of Googling every possible solution